# How do I run a template Beamer in overleaf?

Tags: beamer, xetex, libertine, biolinum

I have a presentation and I want to work with the template given in the
following link https://github.com/klingtnet/beamer-template, but I don't know how to compile it in overleaf. Can you please help me, because I'm not a specialist in latex?

[image]

Comment: Just upload the files in https://github.com/klingtnet/beamer-template/tree/master/content to your Overleaf project and compile `presentation.tex`.

Comment: @Marijn  I have already done this but it does not work, it shows me errors during compilation. Thank you

Comment: I forgot to mention: also switch the compiler to XeLaTeX in the Overleaf menu (top left button in your screenshot, then around halfway down you can choose the compiler).

Comment: @Marijn  Thank you very much my friend. I just did this, and it shows me this message  "You are approaching your compile timeout limit. Upgrade to Overleaf Premium for 4x more compile time." I think because I have just a free account, is there a technique I can do? Or if I want to work with Texmaker, what should I do?

Comment: you would have to have a very large document to run out of time, are you sure you do not have an error making it loop?

Comment: You could remove line 18 (`\input{example}`) to see if that helps. If you want to compile it on your own machine with TeXmaker then the procedure is more or less the same, you download the files to your computer, open the `presentation.tex` file, and press the correct button or menu option to compile (I'm not sure which button that is, I don't use TeXmaker myself). But indeed as David mentions there could also be an issue with the current code that causes the long compile time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know, I just downloaded the model  from the  link and I'm trying to compile it

Comment: @Marjin it always gives me this message "Sorry, your compilation took too long to run and timed out. The most common causes of timeouts are...". Can you please try compiling it on your computer with a free accounte overleaf?

Comment: @pospos I just tried on overleaf it does time out probably looking for missing fonts, I'll look

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, I'm waiting for you, my friend. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It times-out looking for missing fonts.

if you comment out lines 13-15 of `preamble.tex`

```
%\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum}
%\setromanfont{Linux Libertine}
%\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Consolas}
```

It works.

Alternatively you could upload these fonts to your project

[Copy on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rcgndtyypkvx)

Comment: Thank you very much  Mr David